# .Net application with MySql connector on linux

Tags: c#, mysql, linux, connector

I am making an application that uses MySql.Data.dll to connect to the database. It works fine on Windows, but refuses to work on Linux(tried on Centos and Fedora). I've tried compiling on Visual C# Express and MonoDevelop, downloading another version on the dll, making the project .Net 2.0 ... nothing works.

I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.ArgumentException: Format of initialization string does not conform to specifications at index 73.
>     at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.ParseConnectionStringNonOdbc (System.String connectionString) [0x00401] in /usr/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/DbConnectionStringBuilder.cs:771 
>     at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.ParseConnectionString (System.String connectionString) [0x00017] in /usr/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/DbConnectionStringBuilder.cs:531 
>     at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString (System.String value) [0x0001e] in /usr/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/DbConnectionStringBuilder.cs:97 
>     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor (System.String connStr) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString (System.String value) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor (System.String connectionString) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection:.ctor (string)
>     at Plate.MySQLConnection.Select (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView& _dataGrid, System.String[] select, System.String from, Plate.FieldValue[] where, System.String[] order_by) [0x0000f] in /home/ukus/Desktop/MonoDev/Place/MySQLConnection.cs:241 
>     at Plate.GlavniForm.ReloadMeseci () [0x0006f] in /home/ukus/Desktop/MonoDev/Place/GlavniForm.cs:43 
>     at Plate.GlavniForm..ctor () [0x00020] in /home/ukus/Desktop/MonoDev/Place/GlavniForm.cs:28 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Plate.GlavniForm:.ctor ()
>     at Plate.Program.Main () [0x0000c] in /home/ukus/Desktop/MonoDev/Place/Program.cs:18 
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: Format of initialization string does not conform to specifications at index 73.
>     at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.ParseConnectionStringNonOdbc (System.String connectionString) [0x00401] in /usr/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/DbConnectionStringBuilder.cs:771 
>     at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.ParseConnectionString (System.String connectionString) [0x00017] in /usr/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/DbConnectionStringBuilder.cs:531 
>     at System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString (System.String value) [0x0001e] in /usr/src/mono/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.Common/DbConnectionStringBuilder.cs:97 
>     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor (System.String connStr) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString (System.String value) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor (System.String connectionString) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection:.ctor (string)
>     at Plate.MySQLConnection.Select (System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView& _dataGrid, System.String[] select, System.String from, Plate.FieldValue[] where, System.String[] order_by) [0x0000f] in /home/ukus/Desktop/MonoDev/Place/MySQLConnection.cs:241 
>     at Plate.GlavniForm.ReloadMeseci () [0x0006f] in /home/ukus/Desktop/MonoDev/Place/GlavniForm.cs:43 
>     at Plate.GlavniForm..ctor () [0x00020] in /home/ukus/Desktop/MonoDev/Place/GlavniForm.cs:28 
>     at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Plate.GlavniForm:.ctor ()
>     at Plate.Program.Main () [0x0000c] in /home/ukus/Desktop/MonoDev/Place/Program.cs:18

The application builds successfully on both Visual C# Express and MonoDevelop.

Comment: The application builds successfully on both Visual C# Express and MonoDevelop.

Comment: show the code that is giving this error

Comment: There is no "code that is giving this error".

Comment: The compilation runs without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. The application did not work on Linux because of connection string. The problem probably lies in Mono not being equivalent to .Net.